# What is the official website for the lynx, text based webbrowser?

Tags: lynx

The: http://lynx.isc.org/ is not loading.

Is it the https://lynx.invisible-island.net/ what is the official for the "lynx", the text-based webbrowser?

Comment: On a Debian "testing" distribution, `aptitude show lynx` says `Homepage: https://lynx.invisible-island.net`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The homepage for Lynx has moved more than once, as discussed in this [development page](https://invisible-island.net/lynx/lynx-develop.html#hosting):

> However, things change. Paul Vixie left ISC in mid-2013 to form a new company. At the time, that did not affect Lynx—from ISC's standpoint Lynx was just a box in a rack of servers. For the last four years of Lynx's stay at ISC, I did all of the software maintenance for the project. Still, a box in a rack costs money for electricity. Late in 2015, ISC shifted away from this style of project support, to reduce costs. I expanded my website to incorporate Lynx (roughly doubling the size of the site).
>
> Old site:
>
> ```
> http://lynx.isc.org/
> ftp://lynx.isc.org/
> ```
>
> New site:
>
> ```
> https://lynx.invisible-island.net/
> ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/lynx/
> ```

This new site is still the current homepage as of February 2018.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, `http://lynx.invisible-island.net/` is the current official home page for the Lynx text-based web browser.

Unless [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey) says otherwise.  ([He doesn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421787/116858))

The move is mentioned in [the `CHANGES` document](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES) for release "2.8.9dev.7" in December 2015:

```
* move homepage for Lynx from
    http://lynx.isc.org
  to
    http://lynx.invisible-island.net
  because ISC has ended support -TD
```

Comment: The problem with looking at CHANGES is that the site might have moved in the past 2 years.

Comment: @RonJohn You mean "last 6 months"? The latest entry in that file is from July 2017. Well, in that case I would not really be expecting to find the document at that site.